# No events for dynamically generated input tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, jquery-events

I have dynamically generated some input tags for a web application.

```
function FormElement () {
    
    this.formElement = $('<div class="formElement"></div>');
    this.formElement.append('<label for=""></label>');
    this.formElement.append('<input type="text" />');

    FormElement.prototype.addIds = function (id) {
        this.formElement.find('label').attr({'for':id});
        this.formElement.find('input').attr({'id':id});
        return this.formElement; 
    };
    FormElement.prototype.addLabelText = function (value) {
        this.formElement.find('label').html(value);
    };
    FormElement.prototype.addInputValue = function (value) {
        this.formElement.find('input').attr({'value':value});
    };
    FormElement.prototype.addClass = function (className) {
        this.formElement.attr({'class':className});
    };
    FormElement.prototype.append = function (selector) {
        $(selector).append(this.formElement);
    };
}
```

The appended elements do not seem to have associated click, select etc.. events. I read you can you `.on()`. I would like to associate all possible events to all types of elements in a general way.  What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: I think you want: `$("#container_id").on("click", '.formElement input[type="text"]', function () { });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to assign a default behavior on click event for all inputs with a specific class, say 'foo':

```
$(document).on('click','input.foo', function(){
    /* your function here */
});
```

If you don't go this way and try the following:

```
$('input.foo').click(function(){
     /* your function here */
});
```

then **the behavior will be added only to existing elements, not to those added after the script executed**.

Comment: Thankyou for your solution. I have used your solution with the selector @Ian suggested. I'm still not seeing an event.

Comment: Can you post the code you're trying? On **which** event do you want do **what**?

Comment: $(document).on('click','.formElement input[type="text"]', function(e){
            console.log(e);
    });

Comment: Can you try this to see if the alert appears when you click on an input? `$(document).on('click','.formElement input[type="text"]', function(e){ alert('foo'); });`

Comment: no seeing an alert window. I'm using using requirejs, does this have any relevance

Answer (score 0):

you have to use  [On() function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) on them

> Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

```
$("button").on("click", 'selector',notify);


$("target").on("change",'selector', notify);
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically generated element's you need event delegation -

```
$(document).on('change','.yourInputClass',function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/